# Random Items from Query

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a database with 16000 rows. I want to grab a random 400 rows.

How would I accomplish this task? Would I do it in Sql? Or select all 16000 rows and then dump a random 400 into an array?

I'm new to PHP and programming..

Thanks for any help.

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM AllImages') or die ('Error query: '.mysql_error ());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM AllImages order by RAND() limit 400`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400
```

Also, `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM AllImages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400');
```

although it's not very well performing solution if you have a lot of rows